# Facebook SDK get count of friends that has been invited

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to invite friends:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:]
```

How can I get count of friends that has been invited to app? Something like this:

```
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:@"Hello"
                                                    title:@"My app"
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
//Something bad happened
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
//canceled
                                                          } else {
//request sended. How many friends were invited?????
                                                          }
                                                      }}];
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to that problem ?

Comment: Ok answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358156/facebook-ios-presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-to-return-selected-friends